# Propagate wheel event from a scrollable container to the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, scroll

##### Problem

I have an element which is scrollable horizontally (with `overflow-x: scroll;`). If I hover mouse over it and use the mousewheel (vertically), it will result in no action - because the element being scrollable captures the mousewheel.

I want scrolling with mousewheel on that element to scroll the window up / down instead, just as it would if the element was not scrollable.

##### Solutions considered

I tried using the `wheel` event and preventing default if scrolling is vertical, but it doesn't do anything.

I also considered capturing `deltaY` of `scroll` event and using it to manually scroll the window with `window.scrollTo()`, however, I'm afraid that each browser / OS may have a different implementation of scrolling, making it hard to duplicate the behavior reliably on all platforms.

Implementing the scroll behavior manually with the help of some scrolling library instead of relaying on the browser - this is the last resort.

##### Question

Is there a way to somehow propagate that wheel event to the parent (window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to tell the element not to listen to vertical scrolling. By default, the property is `visible`, with one exception:

> Setting one axis to visible (the default) while setting the other to a different value results in visible behaving as auto. ([MDN Webdocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#description))

This means that you need to explicitly set `overflow-y: hidden` to get the behaviour you want.

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
#outer{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#hscroll{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="outer"><div id='hscroll'><p>Scrollme</p></div></div>
```